# Find the number of elements in the centre of this group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = \{e, x, x^2, x^3, y, xy, x^2y, x^3y\}$ with $O(x)=4, O(y)=2$,  and $xy=yx^3$. Then what is the number of elements in the centre of $G$?

Comment: O($x$) refers to the order of element x.

Comment: You may refer to the proof for [$Z(S_4) = \{e\}$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Symmetric_Group_is_Trivial).

Comment: @GNU Supporter I think the given group is another group.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thx for your comment.  I confused $Z(S_4)$ with [$Z(D_4$)](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/center-of-dihedral-groups/).

Answer (score 0):

Sketch answer:

From the relation you can check that each $x^iy$ does not commute with $x$.

Next you can check if $x,x^3$ commute with $y$. You can check that what is left is the center of $G$.